# How to display questions based on the answer?

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am making something where the user gets a question with matching answers and based on the user's answer there has to be a next question and so on.

I have a database with 2 tables: Questions and Answers. They are stored with obviously Questions and Answers. These tables have columns.

Question table has: `ID`, `Description` (which is the question itself)

Answers table has: `ID`, `Question ID`, `Next Question ID`, `Description`
(which is the answer itself).

The IDs of both tables are `AUTO_INCREMENT`. The `Question ID` of the Answer table represents the ID of the matching Question and the `Next Question ID` represents the `ID` of the Question where its going  (so.. the next question).

I have everything set up, but i just don't know how to work it out in Laravel and make it a working machine and eventually display it. I have no experience using laravel whatsoever. Also i haven't worked with queries either. Can someone please help?

I have already have MVC. this is my Controller:

```
use App\Models\Question;
use App\Models\Answer;

class Questioncontroller extends Controller
{


    public function index() {

        $Questions= Question::all();
        $Answers= answer::all();


        return view('Question', [
            'Questions' => $Questions,
            'Answers' => $Answers,

        ]);
    }
    
}
```

Let me know if you need more information

Comment: I think i haven't been clear enough. so here is a quick explanation. The questions needs to be displayed for the user with the matching answers. based on what the user answered there has to be a next question and so on. Thats why the Question ID and Next Question IDs are for.

Comment: Please [edit] your question whenever you have updates or clarifications, don't hide content in the comments. See also [ask].